# Can’t join quickblox one of my two dialogs after app was in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, quickblox

I’ve created chat as described at tutorial:
[SimpleSample-chat users-ios](http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios)

I have two dialogs which I get using dialogsForPage method of QBRequest class and store them. Later I switch between dialogs using leave/join QBChatDialog's methods and it works fine.

When app goes to background I disconnect QBChat instance, when it returns  to foreground – connect:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[QBChat instance] disconnect];
}
 
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[QBChat instance] connectWithUser:user];
}
```

Then I join dialog which was previously opened and it is joined successfully, however when I try to switch to another dialog(which was joined and lived before app had went to background) onJoin and onJoinFailed blocks have never called and my messages are not sent. If I try to join this dialog one more time I get error(onJoinFailed is called): "Cannot create/join room when already creating/joining/joined."

Shortly: join dialog1 -> leave dialog1 -> join dialog2 -> app in background -> app in foreground -> join dialog2 -> leave dialog2 -> can't join dialog1

Can you help me with this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed in Quickblox SDK version 2.4.6

Comment: It was fixed for situation when I use one dialog. However if I switch between two dialogs(which I store in dictionary), one dialog can't be joined after app was in background.

Comment: Please try latest Quickblox SDK 2.5, it has new methods for QBChat, you should try them. Let me know if it still not working there.